# в директории (а)есть другая директория(б).Как записать все файлы директории (а) включая файлы директории (б) в список

Tags: python, файлы

Есть программа:

```
import os

from pathlib import Path 


source = Path('D:\\current_dir')

a = os.listdir(source)
print()
# возврашает

#a = ['one_more_dir', '20 String Methods.docx', '20191201153648.zip', '5efb682f752f46906fc79b2f9094ddd2.jpg', 'fortnite.jpg', 'u9o1t3aemesy.png']
```

Где, `a` - это список "детей" директории `current_dir`, но первый элемент списка `а` - это директория `one_more_dir`.

Как мне получить список файлов директории `one_more_dir` и записать их в список `а`?

В самом списке не должно быть директории `one_more_dir`. При этом, я не знаю, есть ли в директории `one_more_dir` другие директории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `os.walk()` рекурсивно пройдёт все директориям и в список `all_files` добавит названия файлов

```
   import os
    all_files=[]
    for d, dirs, files in os.walk('c:/1'):
        for f in files:
            all_files.append(f)
    print(all_files)
```